# normpdf behaves strangely

Tags: matlab, probability-density

In the following manner,

```
function ret = f(pIx5, dS)
    sigma = 1;    

    rho = dS(1);
    theta = dS(2);

    mu_x = rho*cos(theta);

    display(pIx5);
    display(mu_x);

    pdf = normpdf(pIx5, mu_x, sigma);

    ret = max(pdf);
end
```

I get the following error message,

```
pIx5 =
       54   65   11    0    0

mu_x =
       11.9218

Error using normpdf (line 36) Non-scalar arguments must match in size.

Error in f (line 11)

        pdf = normpdf(pIx5, mu_x, sigma);
```

But, it works fine in the following manner,

```
function ret = f(pIx5, dS)
    sigma = 1;    

    rho = dS(1);
    theta = dS(2);

    pIx5 = [54,65, 11, 0, 0];

    mu_x = 11.9218;

    display(pIx5);
    display(mu_x);

    pdf = normpdf(pIx5, mu_x, sigma);

    ret = max(pdf);
end
```

What is going on here?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm willing to bet significant amounts of money that the problem is with the [type](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/class.html) of your input `pIx5`. Note this:

```
>> pdf = normpdf([54 65 11 0 0], 11.9218, 1);  % Works fine
>> pdf = normpdf(uint8([54 65 11 0 0]), 11.9218, 1);
Error using normpdf (line 36)
Non-scalar arguments must match in size.
```

Why does it give a size error for what should be something related to the type? Taking a look at the code for [`normpdf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normpdf.html) answers that. From lines 33-37, R2016b:

```
...
try
    y = exp(-0.5 * ((x - mu)./sigma).^2) ./ (sqrt(2*pi) .* sigma);
catch
   error(message('stats:normpdf:InputSizeMismatch'));
end
```

Basically, *any* error in evaluating that equation is reported as a size mismatch error. In this case, it is actually an issue with [`exp`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exp.html) not working for integer data types (it only support `single` and `double` types):

```
>> x = uint8([54 65 11 0 0]);
>> mu = 11.9218;
>> sigma = 1;
>> y = exp(-0.5 * ((x - mu)./sigma).^2) ./ (sqrt(2*pi) .* sigma);
Undefined function 'exp' for input arguments of type 'uint8'.
```

The solution then? Just cast your offending inputs to `single` or `double` first:

```
pdf = normpdf(double(pIx5), mu_x, sigma);
```

Comment: Exactly!  How can I get around this ?

Comment: That is seriously a f***ed up error.  This is the first time I have seen MATLAB producing an error message with no correlation to what is actually happening in the method.

Comment: @anonymous Just cast your inputs to `double` prior to using `normpdf`.

Comment: Good catch! That `try` `catch` is really malevolent.